# Is there any difference between static memory allocation and automatic memory allocation?

Tags: c++

I was reading about Static Memory Allocation and Dynamic Memory Allocation. Static memory is basically `int a = 2;` where space for `a` is allocated on stack. But if I do, `int * a = new int; *a = 3`, here memory is allocated on heap. But then, can the former also be called as automatic memory allocation? Thanks!

Comment: the "former" is two instructions. do you mean `int * a = new int;`? There is automatic allocation for the  `int *` variable

Comment: Read up on [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration).

Answer (score 8):

**Forget about stack and heap.** These terms are not defined in the C++ standard (except for things like stack unwinding and `std::stack`). What you are talking about is *storage duration*, which can be:

- static
- thread
- automatic
- dynamic

Dynamic storage duration is applied to objects created using `new`. Such objects live until you `delete` them.

Automatic is for block-scope variables not declared `static` or `extern`, like local variables in a function. These are automatically (aptly) destroyed when the block ends.

Thread is for variables declared `thread_local`. These exist until the thread in which they were created finishes.

Static is for anything else, generally variables declared at the file scope or with the `static` keyword. Such variables exist for the duration of the program.

Comment: Understood, but just asking, isn't it right that when I allocate memory using `new`, it's allocated on heap and when I go for automatic, it's allocated on stack?

Comment: No. When you allocate using `new`, memory is allocated with the *free store*. When you have automatic storage, it could be on the stack, it could be optimized out, it could be stored in a register...

Comment: As a practical matter (common behavior on reasonable architectures), it is useful to think about automatic allocations being in the stack, and allocations with `new` or  `malloc` being in the heap.  You should be aware that the standard does not enforce that.  But understanding the common behavior can still help you in coding well and as an approximation toward the behavior the standard does specify.